# Regular Expression: Finding String and digits

Tags: java

I have a file with lines of string printet by my toString like this:

> [Name: *value*][age: *value*][cprNumber: *value*][group:
>   *value*][Active: *value*][Average Grade: *float value*]

I have a Class with a read method that reads the file and return each line as objects in an ArrayList.

Now back in my Main Class, I'm trying to look at each object in the List and this is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to find the Objects that have Average Grade above 4.
Can someone please help me with the correct regular expression?

Comment: How are the lines stored in the `ArrayList`? As Strings?

Comment: It would be much easier if instead of storing the lines as Strings, you created an object to model the line.

Comment: are those bracket `[ and ]` also the double quotes in last brackets really in your file? or you just added it in the question to make it "clear" ?

Comment: the [] are in the file, the "" are not...

Comment: @Henrik_F urrr... I just gave an answer with the quotes...:(

Comment: :) yes saw that, and thanks by the way. I'm looking into the examples at the moment. i like the row.split idea.

Comment: @Henrik_F updated without quotes and with a small example

Comment: I just tried it out in my code. My value is 8.0 and with that number it writes 8.0] instead of just 8.0

Comment: You can split on `[` or `]` or both - this will remove the last `]` from your `String`, `split("[\\[]]++")` ought to work. I would really recommend my approach as it's a little more flexible.

Comment: @bmorris591 im trying out your code at the moment, but it throws an error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
 at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
 at dk.itu.assignment10.The_creator.main(Main_Class.java:87)`

even thou I agree to the point that its a lot more flexible, its also very complex for what I currently need.

the `split("[\\[]]++")` you provided, prints the entire string...

Comment: I had a typo in the code, "Grade" rather than "Average Grade" - corrected now.

Comment: ahhh there we go... And now it works. I need to print the entire string thou, meaning where the Average Grade is above 4, send that String to a Method that will write it to a file.

Comment: Then add the whole `String` to the `List` and make it a `List<String>`.

Comment: Bingo... nailed it! Thanks @bmorris and kent for your excellent help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to parse each `String` and put the key->value pairs into a `Map`. This will allow you to access other values if you need to.

All you need to do is, in the loop, get the key from the `Map` and parse it to a `float` and check for it's value

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final String[] strings = new String[]{
        "[Name: Bob][age: 27][cprNumber: 1234][group: A][Active: true][Average Grade: 4.1]",
        "[Name: Alice][age: 17][cprNumber: 4321][group: A][Active: true][Average Grade: 4.5]",
        "[Name: James][age: 33][cprNumber: 2134][group: B][Active: true][Average Grade: 2.2]",
        "[Name: Frank][age: 23][cprNumber: 3124][group: B][Active: false][Average Grade: 3.1]"
    };
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^:]++):\\s([^]]++)]");
    final Collection<Float> grades = new LinkedList<Float>();
    for (final String string : strings) {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            final String key = matcher.group(1).trim();
            final String value = matcher.group(2).trim();
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
        final float grade = Float.parseFloat(map.get("Average Grade"));
        if (grade > 4) {
            grades.add(grade);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{Name=Bob, Active=true, cprNumber=1234, age=27, Average Grade=4.1, group=A}
{Name=Alice, Active=true, cprNumber=4321, age=17, Average Grade=4.5, group=A}
{Name=James, Active=true, cprNumber=2134, age=33, Average Grade=2.2, group=B}
{Name=Frank, Active=false, cprNumber=3124, age=23, Average Grade=3.1, group=B}
[4.1, 4.5]
```

This example has a `String[]` but using a `List` will make no difference.

You could create an `Object` to hold the value - this would be a more OO approach.

**EDIT**

Here is an example using `spilt`. It's a lot more hardcoded -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final String[] strings = new String[]{
        "[Name: Bob][age: 27][cprNumber: 1234][group: A][Active: true][Average Grade: 4.1]",
        "[Name: Alice][age: 17][cprNumber: 4321][group: A][Active: true][Average Grade: 4.5]",
        "[Name: James][age: 33][cprNumber: 2134][group: B][Active: true][Average Grade: 2.2]",
        "[Name: Frank][age: 23][cprNumber: 3124][group: B][Active: false][Average Grade: 3.1]"
    };
    final Collection<Float> grades = new LinkedList<Float>();
    for (final String string : strings) {
        final String[] values = string.split("[\\[\\]]+|:");
        final float gpa = Float.parseFloat(values[12].trim());
        if (gpa > 4) {
            grades.add(gpa);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(grades);
}
```

Output is the same:

```
[4.1, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

regex is not good for number calculation/comparison.

If the double quotes in your question really exist in your file. For your example, you can just get one row, this will give your the float number(in String).

```
row.split("\\"")[1];
```

then you can check if the value of above `>4`, you may need to convert it to number first.

If you could use 3rd part lib, guava has a nice `filter()` function, you could take a look.

**EDIT**

if the double quotes are not in your file, you could still use `split()`

```
String[] arr=row.split("(: |])");
arr[arr.length-1] //this is the float
```

for example:

```
final String[] arr = "[Name: value][age: value][cprNumber: value][group: value][Active: value][Average Grade: 4343.0]".split("(: |])");
    System.out.println(arr[arr.length - 1]);
```

outputs:

```
4343.0
```